# Huge PDF takes time to render while scrolling using pdfviewer.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf.js

I have custom pdf viewer html page for rendering the pdf. i am using pdfjs library for render the pdf. It's working fine for me.

When i open the small pdf file then it downloads and renders the file quickly,
when i open the large pdf then it downloads the pdf file quickly but it takes too much time to render the pdf file.

I can see the large pdf file content but when i scroll down then it hang the whole browser.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How big is this PDF file?

Comment: it's 150 pages PDF file

Comment: and in MB size?

Comment: its size approx 10-15 MB

Comment: Is the PDF file optimized for fast web view?

Comment: arun kamboj, can you add versions you were and are using to make Q&A more useful?

Comment: Post the large PDF so we can see what type of rendering challenges it presents. If it is image heavy then this is possibly the issue, but let us see it.

Comment: @arunkamboj Please award the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

In summary on your OP - since you did not respond to questions or provide example of the PDF you were having trouble with then no-one can give a conclusive answer.  This is a shame because it would have been easy to set up a snippet to probe the issue.

At a guess, I would say it is likely that there is a mismatch between the contents of your PDF file and the capability of pdfjs. If we had your example file we might be able to raise a bug on the [developers git,](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) which seems to be active and well supported.

What follows is a high-level description of the issues involved with creation of a PDF rendering engine, provided to illuminate why you may want to stick with the mainstream built-in rendering engines provided within popular browsers.

Rendering a PDF is a complicated task. If you break it down to component operations it is feasible, but there are several levels of PDF standard that introduced a large array of options. It is likely that either your PDF contains something with a faulty rendering implementation in pdfjs, or something that pdfjs is choking on when it tries to render it.

Some background: The PDF format is both brilliant and fiendish at the same time. Brilliant because of its portability, but fiendish because of the internal structure and storage mechanisms. There is no friendly 'DOM' like with HTML. If we were starting out afresh to develop a portable document format it would not be PDF that we would choose. But PDF currently has too much momentum to be thrown away, period.

To 'render' the contents of a PDF file to a display device or printer, your code  would need to unpack the PDF and render the components (images, formatted text, pages) to the display device. It sounds straightforwad to anyone with experience of HTML DOM manipulation but there is no direct comparison.

PDF is a [vector-based graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) definition language. The most likely equivalent most people would have experienced is SVG.

Anything that is not an embedded image in a PDF file is a vector-based output, except text which is zip-compressed and laid out by x/y co-ordinates rather than continuous strings.

Drawing and layout instructions live in sections (digests) that are linked via pointers like a tree - no simple top-to-bottom read & render process. A PDF can have redundant sections, replaced by some later edit but still present. And while on the subject, unless the PDF file is configured for fast web viewing, the rendering engine has to wait for the entire file to be delivered before it can understand how to display it. Fast web view puts the 'index' and page 1 sections at the top of the file stream to allow the rendering engine to get something out to the screen as fast as possible.

To support PDF adequately you have to be able to render anything the PDF contains and to do this perfectly in line with the PDF standards, otherwise you may find your PDF viewer crashes or is unable to render the entire PDF. You would have to cater for the various Acrobat standard levels, and the shortcuts and bloats that the editing package (Word, Illustrator, InDesign) vendors chuck into the PDF file; layers, thumbnails, etc.

In PDF, text could be stored as vector drawing instructions 'or' references to characters in a font file (like HTML text).

Regarding colors, have a read of the PDF spec and you will see that there are an array of colorspace options that the original PDF producer can decide to use. Some of these are for print devices that use alien color mechanisms. You would have to interpret these to a reasonable device color on the screen.

And then fonts. Fonts might be embedded subsets, or not. You will have to take decisions over what alternative fonts to use if a font mentioned in the PDF is not present when the rendering engine runs. To keep fidelity with the PDF you will need to realised the glyphs as vector graphics on your drawing surface at the scale defined in the PDF.

Given the layering, scaling and rotating features in PDF, you would likely be looking at an html canvas as the drawing surface. Anyone who knows will tell you that in the world of canvas you are pretty much on your own for rendering functions - both the strength and weakness of canvas, though for rendering PDF you will probably want absolute control so most libraries are not going to be of use to you. Meaning you are working with drawing primitives which takes time and can be susceptible to bugs.

Probably your biggest challenge is understanding the full range and scope of what you have to do. This is not impossible, but hard.

In summary on this lecture about challenges of writing a PDF rendering engine - rendering PDF files perfectly is a very complicated undertaking. It will not be surprising if during early release phases such products are felt to be very buggy in terms of not supporting chunks of the PDF specifications. Do not be too hard on the developers - the target they are aiming for is hard. If the developers have the backing and therefore the time to stay with the project then the full set of features in the PDF spec may be covered in their product at some point in time. Ideally they would publish a list of unsupported PDF features so that users could recognise potential issues, though you would never really know there was an issue until a PDF file looked strange when rendered or the engine crashed.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like that you are using older version of PDF.js, Try with newer version